# Swapping magnitized bed plates?

Tags: bed-leveling

I print a lot of stuff, and I was thinking I could get several magnetic bed-plates and when 1 print is done simply have my wife pull the plate off and stick on clean plate and start the print again.
But a friend of mine says that won't work. Because even if the plates are made by the same manufacturer you can't guarantee the bed will be level. 〰

Has anyone ever tried this?

Comment: Hi MattR, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! If you have a Z-sensor instead of a Z-switch you could add a `G29` before each print, if the idea is to change the plate while you are not at home and somebody less experienced need to do some tasks, that could be a solution. The crux is what kind of printer you have, please expand the question by [edit]!

Comment: try it and if you have 1st layer issues consider a raft support.

Answer (score 3):

It is a question of quality:

You better make sure that your plates are the same thickness evenly, and level very similarly. If that can be assured, they can be swapped easily.

In case you have a bed leveling sensor of some sort, you might include a whole bed-leveling cycle in front of every print and exchange between numerous beds, even of slightly variant thicknesses and with dings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,I was also facing the same problem couples of month ago and to solution I had buyed extra plates and **It works perfectly** . Go for the extra beds and buy only from the same manufacturer.

Hope your get your answer